# Chrome Says "Failed to parse SourceMap: appBundle.js.map" After regex handling

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, unicode, typescript

I have followed the answer given me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37716995/remove-niqqud-from-string-in-javascript), then i have written the following script(Typescript):

```
function removeNiqqud(str: string) {
    return str.replace(/[\u0591-\u05C7]/g, '');
}
```

After that, Chrome is complaining through console:

```
Failed to parse SourceMap: http://localhost/<my_project>/www/scripts/appBundle.js.map
```

[When i remove the function and compile again the error is gone, and when i am bringing the function back the error is back also...]

How can i change the regex so chrome will not shout at me?

<strike>**Update:**</strike>

After Chrome updated itself to newest version this night, it's giving me the error even if i remove the function. so it's seems like a bug. In Microsoft Edge for example everything is fine and i am able to debug the *.ts files.

For moderators - consider close the question.

The problem is as described before update.

Comment: May help: [Failed to parse SourceMap](http://paulsalaets.com/posts/failed-to-parse-sourcemap).

Comment: Thanks. I have followed your test. it's not gzipped and it's a valid json.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug why MS Edge/IE11 does not load sourcemap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687049/how-to-debug-why-ms-edge-ie11-does-not-load-sourcemap)