# Unable to find my *.ts files in IE 11 debugger

Tags: angular, typescript, debugging, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

As title says, I'm unable to find my typescript files in IE 11 debugger, as I do in Chrome debugger.

I scrolled down to "Dynamic scripts", but I'm only seeing Javascript files in it.

Would appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug why MS Edge/IE11 does not load sourcemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687049/how-to-debug-why-ms-edge-ie11-does-not-load-sourcemap)

Comment: @toskv it is not a duplicate

Comment: both questions are about sourcemaps not working in IE11..

Comment: @toskv but the answer there is not relevant to my case

Comment: also i'm not working with js files

Comment: yeah, you are.. the way you get to see .ts files in any browser's debugger is if the .js files they produce include the proper source maps. Ts does not run directly in the browser.

Comment: @toskv but he is editing the js files, adding/removing lines from js files, while i don't. i'm only working with ts files so questions about editing js files are not relevant to my case

Comment: how does then your typescript code end up in the browser? Do you not generate javascript files? With the help of the compiler ofcourse.

Comment: I'll explain again my problem because i'm not sure I understand you,
I can see my whole angular project as *.js files in IE debugger, so i believe source map is working. BUT *.js files are not helping me, I need to get the *.ts files in order to do a proper debug, same way i'm able to do with Chrome with webpack

Comment: do some reading on sourcemaps. they might do something else than what you think they do ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solve my problem was to update my NPM & Node JS. After that I was able to find all *.ts files in the debugger

Comment: Hi from what version to what version?

Comment: It was over a year ago so I don't remember, but I updated to the latest

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the following in your tsconfig.json file under compilerOptions?

"sourceMap": true,

Comment: Yes. where it saves the map file?

Comment: @AaYy It should be in the same folder, but it doesn't help you, it just allows the browser to let you debug using TS.